# Implicit differentiation of $\sin(x)=x(1+\tan(y))$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I do most of my studying independently either before I take the class to get ahead or after in order to fix trouble areas.  Right now I'm trying to review Single Variable Calculus.  Anyway, I ran into a road block this weekend.

> **Problem**
>   Find $dy/dx$ through implicit differentiation:
>   $$ \sin (x)=x(1+\tan(y)) $$

**My solution**
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}[\sin (x)]&=\frac{d}{dx}[x(1+\tan(y))]\tag{1}\\
\cos(x)&=(1)(1+ \tan(y))+x(1+\tan(y))^{-1}(\sec^{2}(y))\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{2}\\
\cos(x)&=(1+ \tan(y))+\frac{x(\sec^{2}(y))}{1+\tan(y)}\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{3}\\
\cos(x)-(1+ \tan(y))&=\frac{x(\sec^{2}(y))}{1+\tan(y)}\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{4}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{(\cos(x)-1- \tan(y))(1+\tan(y))}{x(\sec^{2}(y))}\tag{5}
\end{align}$$

**Solution from manual I'm using**
$$\begin{align}
\sin (x)&=x(1+\tan(y))\tag{6}\\
\cos(x) &= x(sec^{2}(y))y' + (1+\tan(y))(1)\tag{7}\\
y'&=\frac{\cos(x)-\tan(y)-1}{x\sec^{2}(y)}\tag{8}
\end{align}$$

The disagreement seems to lie with steps 2 & 7.  Any help figuring out why this disagreement exists would be good.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your second step is indeed incorrect. It looks like you are trying to apply an incorrect version of the power rule. Instead, apply the chain rule and note that $\frac{d}{dx}[1+\tan(y)] = (1+\tan(y))'\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(y) = \sec^{2}(y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/7b01b2da-4ebc-4656-a3e0-6ee2f3abcfa3/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: AWertheim, thank you for your response.  It made me take a second look at what I was doing and I believe I know what I did wrong now.  I want you to know how I interpreted your comment.  You wrote: $\frac{d}{dx}[1+tan(y)] = (1+\tan(y))'*\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\sec^{2}(y)$.  I took this to mean: $\frac{d}{dx}[1+tan(y)] = \frac{d}{dx}(1+\tan(y))*(\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(y))+\frac{d}{dx}(1))=\sec^{2}(y)$.  If that was a wrong interpretation then please elaborate.

Comment: **correction** AWertheim wrote: $\frac{d}{dx}[1+tan(y)] = (1+\tan(y))'*\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\sec^{2}(y)\frac{dy}{dx}$.  I took this to mean: $\frac{d}{dx}[1+tan(y)] = \frac{d}{dx}(1+\tan(y))*(\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(y))+\frac{d}{dx}(1))=\sec^{2}(y) \frac{dy}{dx}$.  If that was a wrong interpretation then please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step (2) is incorrect; the product rule states that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} x (1 + \tan y) &= \frac{d(x)}{dx} (1 + \tan{y}) + x \frac{d(1 + \tan{y})}{dx}\\\\
&= (1 + \tan{y}) + x \left(0 + \sec^2{y} \frac{dy}{dx}\right)
\end{align}$$

Where did the $(1 + \tan{y})^{-1}$ term come from?

Comment: I think I realize the error from reading the comments.  The extra term (1+tan(y))^-1 came from erroneously trying to resolve x*((d(1+tan(y)))/dx).  I took u = 1+tan(y) and I then I differentiated as so: x* ((1+tan(y))^(1-1=-1)) * (sec(y))^2 * dy/dx instead of realizing that it should have been x* ((1+tan(y))^(1-1=0)) * (sec(y))^2 * dy/dx which resolves to x(sec(y))^2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It really helped.

Comment: @user89851 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}[x(1 + \tan(y))] &= (x)\left(\frac{d}{dx}[1 + \tan(y)]\right) + (1)(1 + \tan(y))\\\\
&= (x)\left(0 + \sec^2(y) \frac{dy}{dx}\right) + (1 + \tan(y))\\\\
&= x\sec^2(y) \frac{dy}{dx} + 1 + \tan(y)
\end{align}$$

Essentially, you differentiated incorrectly by introducing the $(1 + \tan(y))^{-1}$ term. I'm not entirely sure where that came from.

Comment: Qaphla, thank you for responding.  I believe I got my answer.  Your answer was similar to T.Bonger's and I only chose T.Bonger's because it was posted before.  Thanks again.